# How do I create a fade-in load effect, one after another image

Tags: jquery, image, load, fade

I've got inspired by the thumb loading effect on [this](http://www.marclagrange.com/timeline/) page, but honestly got no clue how to create such effect, on each thumb.

Who could point me in the right direction, or even give me some lines of codes?

I've seen some other topics related, but those won't work in a situation where many images will be loaded, one after another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script :

```
$(function(){
    $("#listing .img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide().delay(100*index).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Then the html :

```
<div id="listing">
  <div class="img"><img src="http://www.marclagrange.com/files/thumbs/medium/snow-white20091.jpg" alt=""  width="235" height="180" /></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="http://www.marclagrange.com/files/thumbs/medium/soeur-sourire70x50.jpg" alt=""  width="235" height="180" /></div>
</div>
```

And do not forget to include [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mkP2/).

Comment: Ah, just found that part too. Thanks, your the best! =D

Comment: Strangely, I can't seem to get it working. Check this out -> http://iscs.nl/bertschaeffer/newtest.html - No matter what I change from the parameters at delay and fade, it just doesn't load.. :s

Comment: Add the jquery "domready" event. Look at my edited post. ;) I thought you knew jQuery. That's why.

Comment: Well, in fact I do. However, never faced a (small) problem like this. That's why. :) - Well, thanks again mate!