# Loading images one after the other with PHP.

Tags: php

I've got this snippet of PHP-code that loads images out of a directory and throws em all at once to the page. I was wondering how I add a functionality that loads images one after the other, instead of it loading them all at once.

```
$path = "images/page1/";

if (is_dir($path)){
    $handle = opendir($path);
}
else{
    echo 'No image directory';
}

$directoryfiles = array();
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    $newfile = str_replace(' ', '_', $file);
    rename($path . $file, $path . $newfile);
    $directoryfiles[] = $newfile;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach($directoryfiles as $directoryfile){
        if(strlen($directoryfile) > 3){
        echo '<tr><td> <img src="'.$path.$directoryfile.'"/>';
        echo '<br>'.$path.$directoryfile.'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
echo '</table>';

closedir($handle);
```

Thanks.

Comment: This snippet is just a simple, procedural PHP script. It processes all of the files sequentially. One after the other. I think you want to load the images with an interval, for which you'll need to use JavaScript

Comment: You can't do this with PHP. You're going to have to use either CSS animations, JavaScript or a combination of both. Googling "jquery image loop" will give you a lot of very good examples of how to achieve this

Comment: Are u talking about an image slider were images are shown one at a time and continuously changes or u change them yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of build a table of images I would put the first image and I would store the url of the others images ina javascript variable. Then, when you want to load the others images (timer, click event, ...) you just have to change the src parameter of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this with only PHP, becouse PHP will always render the page and show the result all at once. If you just want the effect, you can look at this simple jquery script:

[How do I create a fade-in load effect, one after another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072807/how-do-i-create-a-fade-in-load-effect-one-after-another-image)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jquery is the approach:

```
var dir = "images/page1/";
var fileextension = [".png", ".jpg"];
$.ajax({
//This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured a 'browsable'
url: dir,
success: function (data) {
    //Lsit all png file names in the page
    $(data).find("a:contains(" + (fileextension[0]) + "), a:contains(" + (fileextension[1]) + ")").each(function () { 
        var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host,"").replace("http:///",    "");

            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            //hide a div after 3 seconds
                setTimeout( "$("body").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + "></img>"));",3000 );
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Warning: this code haven't been tested, but it should give you an idea of how to approach your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP if you use [output functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Here is an example, number will be visible one after the other :

```
for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i."\n";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

- [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)
- [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)

Comment: I think he wants to have them display one after another after page load

Answer (score -1):

this may work for you:

```
echo '<table>';
$delay=250;
foreach($directoryfiles as $directoryfile){
        if(strlen($directoryfile) > 3){
            echo '<tr><td data-delay='.$delay.'> <img src="'.$path.$directoryfile.'"/>';
            echo '<br>'.$path.$directoryfile.'</td></tr>';

            $delay+=250;    
        }
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: What is `data-delay`? I assume it's a custom attribute for some jQuery script?

Comment: According to the other questions it's a Twitter Bootstrap custom attribute for **tooltips**. But it's no standard HTML and your example won't work.